# How to multiply columns of two tibbles based on all possible combinations of columns in both?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tibbles like so:

```
library(dplyr)
my_tib1 <- tibble(feature1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), feature2 = c("AA", "BB", "AA", "BB", "AA", "BB"), number = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6))
my_tib2 <- tibble(feature3 = c("TT", "TT", "FF", "FF"), feature2 = c("AA", "BB", "AA", "BB"), number = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8))
```

which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  feature1 feature2 number
  <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>
1 A        AA          0.1
2 A        BB          0.1
3 B        AA          0.3
4 B        BB          0.4
5 C        AA          0.05
6 C        BB          0.05

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  feature3 feature2 number
  <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>
1 TT       AA          0.1
2 TT       BB          0.4
3 FF       AA          0.3
4 FF       BB          0.2
```

Note that `feature2` has the same categories in both tibbles. The `number` is unique for each combination of `feature1` and `feature2` in my_tib1 and `feature2` and `feature3` in my_tib2.

For context: The `number` column represents marginal probabilities and I'd like to multiply the marginal distributions to get joint distributions (I'm aware of the assumptions).

What I think this requires is to get all possible combinations of feature 1, feature2, and feature3 and multiply their `number` in a new tibble column. The resulting tibble should have a length of 12: 3 x feature1, 2 x feature2, 2 x feature3.

The final tibble should something like this:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 6
  feature1 feature2 feature3  number.x  number.y  number.mult
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A        AA       TT        0.1       0.1       0.01
2 A        AA       FF        0.1       0.4       0.04
...
```

with the numbers in number.mult adding up to 1.

I have tried the following and I think I'm close but it doesn't quite work:

```
my_tib1 %>% full_join(my_tib2, by = "feature2") %>% mutate(number.mult = number.x*number.y)
```

This just gives me the 12x6 tibble I'm looking for but the numbers in number.mult do not add up to 1.

Comment: But 3 (feature1) x 2 (feature2) x 2 (feature3) = 12, not 24...

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I just changed that part. I'm looking for 6x4=24 combinations.

Comment: I realize that some context would be helpful, which I've added to the question. I'm looking to multiply two marginal distributions to get a joint distribution. The ```number``` column are the marginal distributions for the respective feature combination.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do or how you get to "24 combinations".  Please define the **24 row** dataframe you expect form your sample input.  Am I correct in thinking that your clarification means you think @Wimpel's solution does not meet your needs?  I cannot fault their logic...

Comment: The supplied tibbles have different numbers to your worked example input and output?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just figuring out what my actual problem is. You're right, there's no way to get 24 combinations. 12 is the right number. I think the problem I'm running into is that after multiplying the marginal distributions to get said 12 combinations, they don't add up to 1. E.g. Wimpel's solution adds up to 2.25. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data.table format
setDT(my_tib1); setDT(my_tib2)
# create all unique combinations
DT <- CJ(ft1 = my_tib1$feature1, 
         ft2 = my_tib1$feature2, 
         ft3 = my_tib2$feature3, unique = TRUE)
# join relevant data
DT[my_tib1, `:=`(number.x = i.number), on = .(ft1 = feature1, ft2 = feature2)]
DT[my_tib2, `:=`(number.y = i.number), on = .(ft3 = feature3, ft2 = feature2)]
# final computation
DT[, number.mult := number.x * number.y][]
#    ft1 ft2 ft3 number.x number.y number.mult
# 1:   A  AA  FF      0.1      0.3        0.03
# 2:   A  AA  TT      0.1      0.6        0.06
# 3:   A  BB  FF      0.2      0.8        0.16
# 4:   A  BB  TT      0.2      0.4        0.08
# 5:   B  AA  FF      0.3      0.3        0.09
# 6:   B  AA  TT      0.3      0.6        0.18
# 7:   B  BB  FF      0.4      0.8        0.32
# 8:   B  BB  TT      0.4      0.4        0.16
# 9:   C  AA  FF      0.5      0.3        0.15
#10:   C  AA  TT      0.5      0.6        0.30
#11:   C  BB  FF      0.6      0.8        0.48
#12:   C  BB  TT      0.6      0.4        0.24
```